# Getting errors while compiling?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

I am getting these errors when I am compiling my code. I have all the headers under user/include

```
g++ -Ip_appmanager/inc -Icore/inc p_appmanager/src/appmanager_process.cpp -o p_appmanager/obj/appmanager -lpthread -lparser
p_appmanager/src/appmanager_process.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
p_appmanager/src/appmanager_process.cpp:33:21: error: ‘getpid’ was not declared in this scope
p_appmanager/src/appmanager_process.cpp:101:19: error: ‘fork’ was not declared in this scope
p_appmanager/src/appmanager_process.cpp:105:70: error: ‘execl’ was not declared in this scope
p_appmanager/src/appmanager_process.cpp:109:19: error: ‘getppid’ was not declared in this scope
p_appmanager/src/appmanager_process.cpp:124:19: error: ‘fork’ was not declared in this scope
p_appmanager/src/appmanager_process.cpp:128:61: error: ‘execl’ was not declared in this scope
p_appmanager/src/appmanager_process.cpp:132:19: error: ‘getppid’ was not declared in this scope
p_appmanager/src/appmanager_process.cpp:147:19: error: ‘fork’ was not declared in this scope
p_appmanager/src/appmanager_process.cpp:151:73: error: ‘execl’ was not declared in this scope
p_appmanager/src/appmanager_process.cpp:155:19: error: ‘getppid’ was not declared in this scope
p_appmanager/src/appmanager_process.cpp:170:19: error: ‘fork’ was not declared in this scope
p_appmanager/src/appmanager_process.cpp:175:70: error: ‘execl’ was not declared in this scope
p_appmanager/src/appmanager_process.cpp:179:19: error: ‘getppid’ was not declared in this scope
p_appmanager/src/appmanager_process.cpp: In function ‘void* pingThread(void*)’:
p_appmanager/src/appmanager_process.cpp:302:11: error: ‘sleep’ was not declared in this scope
p_appmanager/src/appmanager_process.cpp: In function ‘void* fifoThread(void*)’:
p_appmanager/src/appmanager_process.cpp:815:22: error: ‘fork’ was not declared in this scope
p_appmanager/src/appmanager_process.cpp:818:72: error: ‘execl’ was not declared in this scope
p_appmanager/src/appmanager_process.cpp:842:64: error: ‘execl’ was not declared in this scope
p_appmanager/src/appmanager_process.cpp:865:72: error: ‘execl’ was not declared in this scope
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

my kernel version is "Linux amit-bhaira 3.8.0-26-generic #38-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 17 21:46:08 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux" . Same code is running on another linux machine.

please help me to fix this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Is your code including <unistd.h>?

Comment: Do you honestly believe we can magically solve your compiler errors without seeing the code?

Comment: @H2CO3: For *those* particular ones, yes.

Comment: If you have the proper man pages installed you can get most info with eg `man getpid` or another function you use. The manual will tell you which header to include and optional linking info.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Wrong attitude.

Comment: sorry for bothering you guys.. actually the same code was working on another system, so I thought that unistd.h is included in some othe header file, but I was not aware of this fact "an old version of gcc (<4.7) which accidentally included unistd.h in some system headers."

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Add `#include <unistd.h>`

It works on other platforms because they are compiling with an old version of gcc (<4.7) which accidentally included unistd.h in some system headers.

Answer (score 6):

From the `fork(2)` man page:

```
SYNOPSIS
       #include <unistd.h>
```

From the `exec(3)` man page:

```
SYNOPSIS
       #include <unistd.h>
```

From the `getpid(2)` man page:

```
SYNOPSIS
       #include <sys/types.h>
       #include <unistd.h>
```

From the `sleep(3)` man page:

```
SYNOPSIS
       #include <unistd.h>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have forgotten `#include <unistd.h>` in your program.

Comment: no i don't, i have mentioned that the same code is running on another linux machine.

Comment: It is probably being sucked in by some other header file - this does happen. Since your code is intentionally using things like `fork` and `execl`, you should include it yourself, and not rely on it being included indirectly.