# linux getpid System call error

Tags: c++, linux, kernel

I got htis error when trying to run a c++ prog on linux-mint , 
$ make

```
g++ -c -O3  common.cc   
common.cc: In function ‘float getCurrentMemoryUsage()’:
common.cc:11:40: error: ‘getpid’ was not declared in this scope
  string pid = intToStr(unsigned(getpid()));
```

what is the steps to fix this, thanks in advance.

Comment: Include the header file that declares getpid? Assuming this is your program.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting errors while compiling?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836865/getting-errors-while-compiling)

Answer (score 4):

From the [`getpid(3)` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getpid):

> ```
> SYNOPSIS
>        #include <unistd.h>
> ```